# Composition of a subharmonic function and a holomorphic function is harmonic.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, holomorphic-functions

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^2 \equiv \Bbb C$ and $u$ be a subharmonic function on $f(\Omega)$. Then show that the function $u \circ f$ is harmonic on $\Omega$.

Since $u$ is subharmonic on $f(\Omega)$ it is quite clear that $u \circ f$ is subharmonic on $\Omega$ because the function $u \circ f$ satisfies sub mean value property on $\Omega$. If we can show that the function satisfies super mean value property on $\Omega$ then we are done with the proof. Because then the function satisfies mean value property on $\Omega$ and then by the converse of the mean value theorem we can say that $u \circ f$ is harmonic on $\Omega$.

But how can I show that $u \circ f$ satisfies super harmonic property on $\Omega$?  I got stuck at this stage. Any Cooperation in solving this problem is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Take $\Omega = \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = z$ and $u(z) = |z|^{2}$. Then $f$ is holomorphic, $u$ subharmonic but $u \circ f$ is not harmonic.

Comment: $\Delta(u) \geq 0$, so it is sub-harmonic. Alternatively use Jensen's inequality.

Comment: You are right @harmonicuser.